# Nginx is not updating new uploaded content

Tags: angular, nginx, server, webserver, server-side-rendering

I've created an Nginx configuration for Angular SSR. When I try to update the content the page is not updating. I always used `systemctl reload nginx` and `service nginx reload` as well as `systemctl restart nginx` and `service nginx restart` but nothing works. I also tried tro change my browser and clear my cache. The page is even still running when I shut down the nginx server with `systemctl stop nginx`

I have now tried to visit my website. On the home page the old version is displayed. When I visit a subpage, however, the new version is displayed but the logo is still old.

Here is my Nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name w3tool.net www.w3tool.net;

    if ($scheme = http) {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }


    # SSL configuration
    #

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    include snippets/ssl-w3tool.net.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/html/w3tool/browser;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution? I have a similar case, i have angular ssr + nginx + node and when i change files at nginx/html folder ( because i developed something new and i want push the changes ) my page sometimes is blank and is stucked, i have to refresh the website to load the content... it seems like my cache is trying to reach old files or something...